# Is there anyway to get the base point (P) used for ECDH on node.js Crypto module?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I'm attempting to establish an Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDH) protocol between 2 peers, 1 running in a Node.js app and the other one in a C app.

In order to do that I decided to establish the initial parameters (curve and base point) in the Node.js side and then pass them to the C app (basically abstracting the agreement process).

Node.js **Crypto** module is being used but it does not provide means to get the base point generated when calling the `ECDG.generateKeys()` method (guess based since the documentation is not very clear in this topic).

Is the base point already defined in the specification?

Any thoughts on this would be really helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ECC cryptography is really fast compared to other asymmetric primitives such as RSA and standard DH. However, generating the domain parameters for a curve is really slow; think hours even for smaller bitsizes. So generally the curve parameters are chosen from a set of known, *named* curves. Most of the curves that are known are on [the safe curves website](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/) of profs Daniel J. Bernstein and Tanja Lange.

Generally the curve to use within a protocol is always a specific type, e.g. curves over F(p) are called prime curves. Then one set of domain parameters is chosen, e.g. the NIST standardized curves. And finally the set of domain parameters is established. Usually this is performed by name (e.g. just NIST P-256) or by ID (e.g. 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7 or {iso(1) member-body(2) us(840) ansi-x962(10045) curves(3) prime(1) prime256v1(7)} in full).

For Node.JS you chose the parameters (which include the curve and base point) before you generate a key pair *for those parameters*:

```
const alice = crypto.createECDH('secp521r1');
const aliceKey = alice.generateKeys();
```

the first one already sets all 6/7 domain parameters. The key generation then simply generates a random secret value `s` for the private key. After multiplication with base point `G` you will get public point `W`, which completes the set of parameters to perform EC based cryptography.

Comment: I accepted your answer as it is by far more complete than mine. Yeah, I was using curves from the NIST "secure" curves list, the question that came to me at the time was how would Node.js native implementation handle the base point. Thanks for extending the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

So, I've done some more research about this topic and found out that according to the [NIST](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf) specification, each curve has already a defined base point as one of the predefined parameters. I suppose that Node.js Crypto implementation follow this specification so one doesn't have to bother passing around this parameter at all.